# [ARM Cortex-A]: Permission fault due to code region mapped as read/write

Tags: arm, arm64, mmu, armv8, cortex-a

When I try to execute code from a region mapped as read/write (AP[2] == 0), the CPU issues a permission fault (exception class == 0b100001, instruction fault status code == 0b001111). When I change the mapping to read-only (AP[2] == 1), the permission fault goes away. Is this expected behavior from the MMU? I thought executing code from a region mapped as read/write was allowed. Could someone point me to a section in the "Arm Architecture Reference Manual" that explains this?

For reference:

- See ARM DDI 0487I.a, page D8-5136 for information about the AP (access permission) bits
- See ARM DDI 0487I.a, page D17-5657 for information about exception class 0b100001 (Instruction Abort taken without a change in Exception level)
- See ARM DDI 0487I.a, page D17-5680 for information about instruction fault status code 0b001111 (Permission fault, level 3)

Answer (score 0):

ARM DDI 0487I.a, page D8-5142 has the answer.

> **Preventing execution from writable locations**
>
> There are register control fields that can be used to force writable memory to be treated as XN, PXN, or UXN, regardless of the value of the corresponding descriptor fields.
>
> For a stage 1 translation in a translation regime that supports two Exception levels, the corresponding SCTLR_ELx.WXN field does all of the following:
>
> - If the value is 0, then there is no effect on access permissions.
> - If the value is 1, then all of the following apply:
>
>   - If the memory region is writable from EL0, then it is treated as Unprivileged execute-never, regardless of the value of the Block descriptor or Page descriptor UXN field.
>   - If the memory region is writable from the higher Exception level, ELx, then it is treated as Privileged execute-never, regardless of the value of the Block descriptor or Page descriptor PXN field.